# How to handle interviewer interrupting me and doing other actions while talking?

Tags: professionalism, interviewing

I was in an interview yesterday with one of the top Indian "services" company that is also famous for "Applying Thought". :)

The interviewer requested that we do a Skype Video call, and soon he started behaving weirdly. He asked a question, and while I was answering, he started taking screenshots of my Skype video; I kept hearing the screen capture shutter sound. In fact, I said "excuse me" at least a few times.

Well, obviously the first question, he asked me about "Tell me about yourself". I just started "I graduated in two thousand and ..." He interrupted and said I don't want your family history, just tell me what you did recently.

While I tried to answer this question, in just 20 seconds he asked me the next question, "What is the difference between ..."

Again I tried to answer this but he did not allow me to finish though it was just 30 seconds. As I was saying my technical skills, he was googling and was asking me questions related to that. For instance, when I said "I have worked extensively on JQuery". He googled and asked "Can you tell how many APIs are there in JQuery?"

He kept doing these rapid fire, interrupting questions for 45 minutes, then finally asked me "Do you have any questions for me?". Though I honestly wanted to blast him with some stinging questions of my own, I didn't say anything. He just hung up the Skype call. I have almost 15 years of experience, but later when I checked his profile on LinkedIn, he just had 7 years' experience which made my night sleepless. I felt very much harassed.

How can I handle this sort of interview in the future?

Comment: Why do you care what he posts on his linkedin profile? Also how did you maintain patience for 45 minutes with this? Dealing with nonsense for that long may be actually a hidden talent. Still from the description the guy sounds like fake

Comment: Hi oneworld! I've edited your question to better fit our format and hopefully get you more answers and upvotes. Please feel free to [edit](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/posts/32730/edit) it further if I messed anything up or to improve it further. I hope to see you around! :)

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of an interview, for a candidate, is to get an offer. I would remain professional at all time and try to answer questions to the best of my abilities. There is nothing much else you can do.

I can speculate two possibilities for the interviewer actions:

1. He wanted to see how you react under pressure and tried to make you react,
2. He is clueless, does not know what he is doing, and probably inexperienced.

Assuming he is in the first category, this also put him in the second. :-)

Bottom line, the is not much you can do but focus, remain professional, and remember that the interview is just one more obstacle before you can get an offer.

Comment: 3. Maybe this guy is not genuine at all?? = troll

Comment: I agree, it sounds like this guy is completely lost. I would advise mental counseling to him, if you don't want the job off-course :-).

Comment: question is, would you want a job with a company that considers this kind of interview a good idea...

Comment: I don't really value that company anymore. I sent an email to the HR manager that I would like to provide feedback about the interview; I got a rude reply that I am not really put for the next round, better luck next time :| Crap!

Comment: @oneworld sorry to hear that. Good luck with your next opportunity!

Comment: @David I was genuinely holding thinking that its the first case; but taking screenshots did not make me that this is the case, totally unprofessional.

Comment: @oneworld You could still respond to the HR person and say "I was not actually interested in the position anymore, but I thought you would like to know that your interviewer was rude and unprofessional...". Though, it depends how small your industry is. That might burn a few bridges.

Comment: I did this last Friday, and no replies :|

Comment: @oneworld sounds like you might have dodged a bullet.